# What is the difference between a Label VerticalOptions and VerticalTextAlignment?

Tags: xamarin

I have this XAML:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="2" >
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Label Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="End" VerticalTextAlignment="End"  Text="ABC"  />
   <Label Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" Text="DEF" />
</Grid>
```

Can someone explain to me the difference between `VerticalOptions` and `VerticalTextAlignment`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `LayoutOptions` (VerticalOptions) decides where the `Label` is placed within the `View`
- `TextAlignment` (VerticalTextAlignment) decides where the text is placed within the `Label` control

The following example places the `Label` at the vertical start of your `View` and the text at the end of the `Label` control:

```
<Label
    BackgroundColor="Green"
    HeightRequest="400"
    VerticalOptions="Start"
    VerticalTextAlignment="End"
    Text="Hello Xamarin">
</Label>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbAUl.png)

If we change the values, the `Label` will be placed at the vertical end of your `View`, but the text is at the start of the `Label`:

```
<Label
    BackgroundColor="Green"
    HeightRequest="400"
    VerticalOptions="End"
    VerticalTextAlignment="Start"
    Text="Hello Xamarin">
</Label>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pfa7s.png)